# Call action to render a partial View in a AjaxRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How you doing? I hope its good.

I have a "View" called Create and another two "partial" "views", a view is used to render a bootstrap modal and other to render a table, when I do a post in this modal I must to update that table, but when the model state of the modal is invalid I must call his action, how can I do this? I tryed to use return PartialView("ModalProduto", model);

Answer (score 0):

try something like this
function () {

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL/PartialViewAction,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: $(form1.).serialize(), // or make your objects for the partial
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#placeforthepartialview_as_a_modal").html(data);

                    },
                    error: function (e, data) {

                    }
                });
            });
```